# Call PowerShell script file from VBA In Windows 10

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

Since a time, I was using this code and it worked before

```
Sub Call_PowerShell_Script_File_From_Excel_VBA()
'Windows PowerShell ISE >> New Script >> Create 'Hello World.ps1'
'    echo "Hello World"
'    $x = 1 + 1
'    echo $x
'----------------------------------------------------------------
Dim wshShell        As Object
Dim wshShellExec    As Object
Dim strCommand      As String
Dim strOutput       As String

strCommand = "Powershell.exe -File ""C:\Users\Future\Desktop\Hello World.ps1"""
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set wshShellExec = wshShell.Exec(strCommand)
strOutput = wshShellExec.StdOut.ReadAll

MsgBox strOutput
End Sub
```

I was working on Windows 7 and the code was with no problem.
After installing Windows 10, I found the code not working and I got blank message with no output
Any ideas ??

** When testing Tim's code I got this message

```
StdOut:       
StdErr:       File C:\Users\Future\Desktop\Hello World.ps1 cannot be loaded 
because running scripts is disabled on this system. For 
more information, see about_Execution_Policies at 
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
+ CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], 
ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Comment: Can you run that script manually?

Comment: Yes and this what confused me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and see what you get:

```
Sub Call_PowerShell_Script_File_From_Excel_VBA()
    'Windows PowerShell ISE >> New Script >> Create 'Hello World.ps1'
    '    echo "Hello World"
    '    $x = 1 + 1
    '    echo $x
    '----------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim wshShell        As Object
    Dim wshShellExec    As Object
    Dim strCommand      As String
    Dim strOutput

    strCommand = "Powershell.exe -File ""C:\Users\Future\Desktop\Hello World.ps1"""
    Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set wshShellExec = wshShell.Exec(strCommand)
    strOutput = wshShellExec.StdOut.ReadAll()
    Debug.Print "StdOut:", strOutput

    strOutput = wshShellExec.StdErr.ReadAll()
    Debug.Print "StdErr:", strOutput


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have put the result in the main post. How can I enable it on the system?

Comment: No idea - just pointing out the problem.  If you're on a company PC then ask your IT folk.  If you're at home then start here: https://www.google.com/search?q=running+scripts+is+disabled+on+this+system+windows+10+powershell

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/106360/how-to-enable-execution-of-powershell-scripts

Comment: Thank you very much for awesome help. It has been enabled by opening PowerShell as administrator then using `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` then using this command too `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Force`